# Exchange Server Cannot send and receive e-mail (501 5.5.4 Required arguments not present)

Tags: exchange

I am unable to send nor receive e-mails on my new Exchange server.
It is behind a pfSense firewall. All the necessary ports are forwarded to exchange server.
DNS records are valid on DNS provider.
When I check logs for send connector I see error: "501 5.5.4 Required arguments not present"

Here is the log file:

> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.527Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,0,,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,*,None,Set Session Permissions
>
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.527Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,1,,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,*,,attempting to connect
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.528Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,2,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,+,,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.529Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,3,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,<,"220 Outlook.somedomain.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 12 Jun 2023 15:51:29 +0300",
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.529Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,4,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,*,,Proxying inbound session with session id 08DB6B20B9FE760D
>
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.529Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,5,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,>,EHLO Outlook.somedomain.com,
>
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.530Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,6,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,<,250  Outlook.somedomain.com Hello [192.168.xxx.xxx] SIZE PIPELINING DSN ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES STARTTLS X-ANONYMOUSTLS AUTH NTLM X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM 8BITMIME BINARYMIME CHUNKING XEXCH50 SMTPUTF8 XRDST XSHADOWREQUEST,
>
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.530Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,7,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,>,X-ANONYMOUSTLS,
>
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.530Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,8,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,<,220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready,
>
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.532Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,9,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,*, CN=Outlook CN=Outlook 38CAA365A4DE6D9740FCB2B636FD686C 87F62D512216959E0C80550CDC811439C57CC5F4 2023-02-18T21:33:18.000Z 2028-02-18T21:33:18.000Z Outlook;Outlook.somedomain.com,Remote certificate Subject Issuer name Serial number Thumbprint Not before Not after Subject alternate names
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.532Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,10,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,*,,"TLS protocol SP_PROT_TLS1_2_CLIENT negotiation succeeded using bulk encryption algorithm CALG_AES_256 with strength 256 bits, MAC hash algorithm CALG_SHA_384 with strength 0 bits and key exchange algorithm CALG_ECDH_EPHEM with strength 384 bits"
>
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.532Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,11,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,*,87F62D512216959E0C80550CDC811439C57CC5F4,Received certificate Thumbprint
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.532Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,12,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,>,EHLO Outlook.somedomain.com,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.533Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,13,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,<,250  Outlook.somedomain.com Hello [192.168.xxx.xxx] SIZE PIPELINING DSN ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES AUTH NTLM LOGIN X-EXPS EXCHANGEAUTH GSSAPI NTLM X-EXCHANGEAUTH SHA256 8BITMIME BINARYMIME CHUNKING XEXCH50 SMTPUTF8 XRDST XSHADOWREQUEST XPROXY XPROXYFROM X-MESSAGECONTEXT ADRC-2.1.0.0 EPROP-1.2.0.0 XSYSPROBE XORIGFROM XMESSAGEVALUE,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.535Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,14,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,>,X-EXPS EXCHANGEAUTH SHA256 ,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.535Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,15,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,>,,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.541Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,16,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,<,235 ,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.544Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,17,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,*,SMTPSendEXCH50 SendRoutingHeaders SendForestHeaders SendOrganizationHeaders SMTPSendXShadow,Set Session Permissions
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.544Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,18,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,>,XPROXYFROM SID=08DB6B20B9FE760D IP=92.45.72.60 PORT=50231 DOMAIN=mgw01-107.relay01.setrow.com SEQNUM=1 PERMS=1073 AUTHSRC=Anonymous,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.545Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,19,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,<,501 5.5.4 Required arguments not present,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.545Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,20,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,>,QUIT,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.546Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,21,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,<,221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel,
> 2023-06-12T12:51:29.546Z,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,08DB6B20B9FE760E,22,192.168.xxx.xxx:17302,192.168.xxx.xxx:2525,-,,Local

What is my server trying to tell me? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to send and receive internal mails within the Exchange organization?

Did the sender receive any NDR message after trying to send mails to or from your organization?

You can use the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/exchange) tool, run an inbound/outbound SMTP Email test and see if you can get any clues.

Comment: Hello,
No unfortunately, internal mails are not working either.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the Queue Viewer? Are the mails stuck in queue with any errors?
Also make sure the Exchange services are running properly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/deployment-ref/services-overview?view=exchserver-2019